# Servlet 3.1 - Parts - method getParts() Unresolved

Tags: java, file, servlets, methods, undefined

I am trying to use getParts() from import javax.servlet.http.Part;
But it tells me 'Cannot Resolve Method 'getParts()'

```
package connec;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import com.entJa.sd.FileMeta;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

(...)

public class MultipartRequestHandler {
    public static List<FileMeta> uploadByJavaServletAPI(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException {

    List<FileMeta> files = new LinkedList<FileMeta>();

    Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
    (...)
```

Any idea why it cant find this method? I know that it came with servlet 3.0 but I am using 3.1 and tried even downloading the 4.0(not finished version).

```
Error:(29, 41) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getParts()
  location: variable request of type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm Using Intellij IDEA so I get default jar lib - JavaEE-API-5 was included. I downloaded javaee-api-7.0.jar (with Maven) and now it's working!

To be precise, what happened is: Java EE 5 includes the Servlet API 2.5, which does not have the getParts() method, as it was only added in Servlet API 3.0 - Java EE 7 on the other hand includes the Servlet API 3.1.

Comment: @Marcus_Y, i am facing the same problem in netbeans. please help me resolve. am using jdk 1.8 and it also doesnt have the getPart() method. its a simple web project but not a maven web project please.